# "Imported content is empty" error when trying to pull data using =IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to pull the "Trophy points" value from https://trackmania.io/#/player/acf21a42-f517-42cc-a1b2-e8e7693da4ca using the following:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://trackmania.io/#/player/acf21a42-f517-42cc-a1b2-e8e7693da4ca","//*[@id='content']/div/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td")
```

When I try this, the cell returns "#N/A" and when I hover "Imported content is empty". The only reason I can think of is that the data on the website hasn't loaded by the time Sheets attempts to pull the data, so it returns with no value.

Answer (score 0):

your assumption of the not-loaded site is incorrect. the issue is the website itself that uses JavaScript. `IMPORT` formulae of google sheets does not support scrapping of JS elements. any such attempt will lead to `#N/A` error and imported content will be empty. you can always check this by doing:

[image]

Comment: Ah okay. In that case I assume there is no method to pull the data I want with Google Sheets? If not would Excel have the capabilities? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rivalzfb not sure about excel. if so then with some vba script but it depends. also, most of the time there is an alternative website that hosts same data